# Things you can draw with HTML tables

Tags: html, performance, drawing, html-table

So I was watching a [talk](http://velocityconference.blip.tv/file/2290442/) by Google's Marissa Mayer about speeding up Google's pages. They found that a shopping cart icon increased load time by 2%, and users then searched 2% less. They managed to replace the icon with an HTML table.

Here is my attempt at drawing a shopping cart: ([live example page](http://cts-static.net/cart.html))

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table   {border-collapse: collapse;}
            th, td  {width: 8px; height: 8px;}
            th  {background-color: blue;}
            td  {background-color: white;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <!-- this row is just to see alignment -->
            <tr>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- handle -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="14"></td>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="13"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="13"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="14"></td>
                <th colspan="3"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- main body -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="13"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <th colspan="1"></th>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <th colspan="13"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>

            <!-- wheels -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"></td>
                <th colspan="4"></th>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <th colspan="4"></th>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**What can *you* draw in tables?!** Impress us.

Comment: That's not really programming related.

Comment: If you're going to take this route, why not use HTML 5's `canvas` instead?

Comment: Web devs go absolutely nuts if you try to use tables for page layouts.  One can only imagine how they'd react if you used them fo RENDERING IMAGES!!!!

Comment: @Pierreten - Google used this technique for years! (Until images sprites came along). @Charlie - Don't ruin the question :)

Comment: Seen Google's front page HTML lately? They'll happily throw out best practices if it cuts page load by 5-10x.

Comment: This question would have been perfect 9 days ago.

Comment: This question can have more than one correct answer. Please mark community wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh yeah, so you think you can draw in HTML? ;-)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpRcbVXnrds

(Well, it wasn't *me*, but it's still astonishing.)

Answer (score 3):

I drew [this](http://virkkunen.net/b/oh-dear.html) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615413/is-there-any-html-code-that-would-display-an-ellipse-or-a-rounded-rectangle) because I was tired (they wanted "HTML", so I assumed that means *pure* HTML). And that's the limit of my table-drawing skills.

Comment: `<!-- no CSS developers were harmed in the making of this document --> ` -- haha

Comment: Wow, too lazy to anti-alias. :)

Answer (score 3):

HTML source [here](http://www.musigenesis.com/SO/test3.zip) (*warning*: 227K unzips to 6MB HTML file that your browser will hate).

Comment: Yeah, there's a reason nobody does this. :)

Comment: My browser didn't have any issues. (Until I tried testing how well it scaled, at least)

Comment: Only incremented the size by one (using Control/Option +) on Firefox 3.6.3. MacBook Air 2.13 Intel Core 2 Duo OS X 10.6.3 with 2GB memory. Firefox froze almost immediately attempting to redraw it, though there were background processes.

Comment: I don't want to know how long it took to make this. Although it's beautiful, I must say.

Comment: @waiwai933: I didn't make this by hand, and it sounds as good as it looks. :)

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/az3yp/nsfw/c0k56l2

Comment: It got cut off. Link to source?

Answer (score 1):

Using borders in different sizes and colors you can create diagonal lines, and avoid the pixely look:

- [UK Flag](http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/borders/ukflag.html)
- [Switchable Lamp](http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/borders/lampa.html)